# How to get a notification in Android when a built-in app finishes loading

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to create a benchmarking app that launches a few apps and measures the load time. Starting a timer and launching an app (via intents) is the easy part. And, if I have source to the child app, I can either have it record the time and pass that back, or I can just have it kill itself completely at some point. But, how do I know when stock apps have finished loading? Or, how can I make them close automatically so that mine is brought to the foreground again to stop the timer? I know the source for stock apps is public, but I don't think it's practical for me to try to modify it. Or is it? I can't tie my benchmarking app to a specific version of Android.

Specifically, I'm interested in measuring load times for the browser, youtube, and mail.

I've looked at using the ActivityManager to get info about running apps, but I think in that case I would have to poll in the background, and I've read that ActivityManager info is not necessarily always up-to-date, anyway.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The stock apps most likely do not notify after they've finished loading, and even if you'd be able to find a print in logcat to indicate it, there's no guarantee it will be consistent across Android versions. If you have a rooted device where you're able to dump the view tree, it might be possible to look for certain view IDs to verify that an app has finished loading. Then again, those will change between Android versions. I've only seen this work with Python libs on the host side, but it sounds like you want to do it on the device so that might not be an option for you.

Comment: Tethering and running something on the host could be a fall-back plan (though I might try modifying stock apps first). What more can you tell me about the Python libs you mention?

Comment: I haven't been able to find them now, but they're based on TEMA (http://tema.cs.tut.fi/index.html). Basically what it does is pull the view hierarchy, parse it, and use monkeyrunner to talk to the device. Linaro did some work using it (https://blueprints.launchpad.net/lava-test/+spec/ui-drive-test-for-android).

Comment: Okay, thanks a ton for looking into it. It sounds like maybe I could get the same info in the app directly by using the ActivityManager. I'm thinking perhaps I should just work with the native apps' sources and build a version for each version of Android I want to support.

Comment: Yes, I think you'll get more precise measurements by modifying the stock apps' sources than you would get with host side scripting.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just modify the source and build a version of my app for each version of Android/processor. I won't have to target each device specifically, just processor families (Atom/armV7/etc.)

Getting and compiling Android source is [easy](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html)

Building a custom version of a stock AOSP app is also [not that bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759579/how-can-i-modify-and-rerelease-an-aosp-app/)

From there, it's just a matter of using intents to invoke activities and pass information.